# Why is Cage looped back to the day before the invasion?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

Is it explained why Cage returns back to that particular moment in time rather then the moment of invasion?

I understand that when an Alpha dies the Omega resets the day, but that would mean resetting to the moment the invasion started rather then resetting to the previous day and if the day is resetting for Cage again surely that would mean resetting to the day of the invasion not the day before?

Comment: The final reset of the movie was from when the Omega died, so the rules could be different.  I interpret it like, the Omega was dying so it tried to reset to earlier so that it could change tactics, but had sustained too much damage and it died in the process.  Think of it like reverting to a previous save in a videogame when you realize your last quick save is already doomed.

Comment: Apologies if the question is unclear, I am talking about the first time Cage is reset and the subsequent times after that, if the Omega resets because an alpha has died, why does it go all the way back to that moment?

Comment: Is like a 24 hour thing or what ever amount of hours it has set. I think the omega can only reset to 24 hours. Like in the final fight, they kill the omega a few hours before he actually dies, so it resets him a few hours before he gets killied in the original timeline. Maybe they can't control the amount of time they can reset the day.